# Android video playback in landscape orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-videoview

Is it possible to get an Android compiled app to play video in landscape orientation?

I've tried everything I can think of and it just won't play... at least not correctly. It is playing the video as I can hear the sound playing but the screen stays blank.

If I do not lock the apps orientation the video plays fine in portrait orientation but when flipping the device to landscape the video image freezes whilst the audio continues to play... if I then flip the device back to portrait the video continues playing.

I have this problem on both the emulator and a Samsung Galaxy Tab. The same issue also happens with the KitchenSink app video example.

Thanks.
Ramachandran

Answer (score 1):

The emulator will generally have problems playing back video. [This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video) works properly for video in both portrait and landscape.